# Ride By Attack and Pounce on a mount

Tags: dnd-3.5e, mounted-combat, charge

Pounce would allow me to make a full attack on the end of a charge. This bonus also applies on a mounted charge. However, what happens if I combine a mounted charge with a ride-by attack? Can I still make a full attack against my target, or not, since the square he occupies is not (strictly speaking) the end of my charge.

Comment: What mount are you using that has pounce?

Comment: None. I (Or rather, the player for whom this is relevant) has pounce.

Answer (score 6):

### Despite the awkwardness of the situation, yes, you can.

Ride-By Attack itself details how it should be handled. It's mechanic is separated into two steps: normal charge and additional movement.
"Normal charge" part works, well, like normal charge. So, if you are allowed to execute full attack at the end of normal Charge action, you can execute it at the end of the first part and then go to the second one.

---

As I mentioned above pounce on iteratives sounds awkward for me. Still, awkward or not, rules do allow that, so untill your DM bans it, the combination you want may be executed.

Comment: Possibly overstepping the boundaries of this question, but would that mean one can also benefit from the bonuses given by the Leap Attack feat if their mount makes a jump during the charge?

Comment: @Arthaban As far as I know, it is considered that it is a creature who make attacks who must jump to achieve Leap Attack benefit on those attacks. May be if your mount somehow has Leap Attack as well, you may pull all that staff together. Still questionable, though.

Comment: @Arthaban This DM would allow it as an extension of *You [the rider] move at its [the mount's] speed, but the mount uses its action to move* (*PH* 157). That is, a mount jumping, essentially, *is* the rider jumping. (In fact, a mount's ability to jump is *dictated* by it rider: The Ride skill use leap (DC 15) says, "You can get your mount to leap obstacles as part of its movement. Use your Ride modifier or the mount’s Jump modifier, *whichever is lower*, to see how far the creature can jump" (*PH* 80; emphasis mine).)

Answer (score 2):

## When your mount charges, your own pounce isn't applicable

For reference, this answer is based on the [Pounce](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#pounce) special ability's wording in the 3.5 SRD:

> When a creature with this special attack makes a charge, it can follow with a full attack — including rake attacks if the creature also has the rake ability.

The basic rules for [mounted combat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#mountedCombat) use the following wording:

> [...] Your mount acts on your initiative count as you direct it. You move at its speed, **but the mount uses its action to move**.
>
> [...]
> If **your mount charges**, you also take the AC penalty associated with a charge. If you make an attack at the end of the charge, you receive the bonus gained from the charge.

(Emphasis mine)

You direct your mount to make a charge, which is not the same as charging yourself. This means that a human riding, say, a tiger, can direct it to charge and pounce (using the somewhat misnamed 'fight with warhorse' [Ride](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/ride.htm) option). But a catfolk riding a horse can't use his own pounce ability with his horse's charge.

To me, this seems to also make more sense from a thematic/narrative perspective - a tiger or a catfolk can pounce thanks to their own agility, covering the distance to the target in one swift leap. This isn't the case when they are mounted.

Finally, the rules for mounted combat also have this to say:

> If your mount moves more than 5 feet, you can only make a single melee attack. **Essentially, you have to wait until the mount gets to your enemy before attacking**, so you can’t make a full attack.

Which also seem to indicate that pounce shouldn't apply.

Personally, I'd allow pounce-while-mounted for situations where both the mount and the rider can pounce, e.g. a catfolk riding a tiger (it's just too thematically cool to disallow), but we'd treat that as a houserule...

Comment: This answer would be improved by citing the rules for Pounce (and specifying which variant, I would be surprised if they were all worded exactly identically). For example, *Catfolk Pounce* says: *If you use the charge action, ...* which indeed conflicts with *If your mount charges, ...*.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Rider uses Charge action to execute a mounted charge. His mount may have no valid target at the end of the movement, but rider must. It is him who charges, and mount may charge too if it can meet all criteria, but if it can't (or does not want, or more likely rider does not want) it just executes movement part of charge action without attack at the end (still with penalty appropriate for a charge). That is why authors sometimes refer to that activity by saying "mount charges" even if mount usually doesn't follow it's movement with an attack when mounted character charges.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - done - thanks for the feedback.