# How does 3.0 mounted charge work?

Tags: dnd-3e, mount, mounted-combat

In DnD 3.0 (**before the 3.5 revision**), how exactly does charging on a mount work? I've checked the PHB and the DMG, but neither has a lot of detail.

Specifically, who (mount or rider) takes what kind of action? Can the mount also attack? If both have pounce, can either make additional attacks?

I have found answers for various other editions, but not for 3.0.

Comment: @doppelgreener Huh. I didn't even realize we had mount tags, let alone two of them. Thanks for adding those.

Comment: Mounted combat doesn't even work in *Pathfinder*, which had both *3e* and *3.5e* to build on, so it might just not work in *3e* either. (I've done a lot of reading on *3.5e* mounted combat—even written answers about it like [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71351/8610) and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64598/8610)—, but I'm pretty sure that [even the game's authors](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20050125a) don't fully understand it.)

Comment: [Relevant](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95228/ride-by-attack-and-pounce-on-a-mount/95230#95230). I believe, it works mostly the same way back in 3.0. Also see coments under GoBLiN's answer.

Answer (score 2):

From my 3e books (not 3.5):

In the description of the lance it gives some information (PHB p101)

> **Lance, Heavy or Light:** a lance deals double damage when used from the back of a charging mount. A heavy lance has reach. You can strike opponents 10 feet away with it, but you can't use it against an adjacent foes.

In **Charge** (PHB p124) this is also mentioned, which would indicate that the +2/-2 modifiers of a charge stand as well.

I see no mention of the mount getting an attack, but in the *Monster Manual* (p196) description of a Heavy Warhorse:

> These animals are similar to heavy horses but are trained and bred for strength and aggression. A heavy warhorse can fight while carrying a rider, but the rider cannot also attack unless he or she succeeds at a Ride check (DC 10).

Hooves do 1d6+4, and a bite does 1d4+2. Charging allows for a single attack, so the horse should get one or the other. The hooves seems natural, as a trample attack. (Edit, I assumed warhorse, but would think the single attack on a charge would count for other type mounts; so Battlecat would get a claw, a claw, or a bite)

So, provided the rider can pass a DC 10 Ride check, both get an attack.

Comment: Great catch on the MM description. I'll let this sit for a day or two in case someone has a correction, but it looks right to me. Thanks!

Comment: I do love 3e (never went to 3.5 or PF), but man, did you have to search for some things. :-)